# Where to put "innerShiv" in this .load() code fragment?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to insert "innerShiv" into this Code:

```
$(function() {

    var newHash      = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
        baseHeight   = 0,
        $el;

    $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
    baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash) {
            $mainContent
                .find("#guts")
                .fadeOut(200, function() {
                       $mainContent.hide().load(innerShiv(newHash + " #guts"), function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        $pageWrap.css({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });
   });
                        $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                        $("nav a[href='"+newHash+"']").addClass("current");
                    });
                });
        };

    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

This doesn't work yet. Where to put the bracket correctly?

Sources:

http://css-tricks.com/6336-dynamic-page-replacing-content
http://jdbartlett.com/innershiv/

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to use an editor that has some sort basic syntax error highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems are mostly syntax issues like incorrect number of closing brackets etc. Try using an editor like [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) which will highlight these sorts of things for you so you can debug before trying it in a browser. In the meantime I've corrected your code.

```
$(function() {

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;

$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                   $mainContent.hide().load(innerShiv(newHash + " #guts"), function() {
                $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                    $pageWrap.css({
                        height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                    });
                });
});
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href='"+newHash+"']").addClass("current");
                });
            };
    });


$(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

Comment: IE kicks out "Object expected". Safari doesn't work eather now too. Maybe it has something to do with the loading order? This is my one: html5shiv, styles, jquery, scripts, innershiv, dynamic content (this code including).

Comment: Shouldn't you be loading jquery plugins after you load the jquery library?

Comment: Sorry - I hadn't heard of htmlshiv before. I thought it was a jquery plugin.

Comment: ..and Firebug says: missing ) after argument list

Comment: add another 
                     }); - I've edited the answer.

Comment: The above code seems complete to me. The syntax error is probably elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, the problem now moved some rows further. I updated the whole function in my question. Maybe you could have a look?

Comment: Safari-Console says: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: innershiv.

Comment: Ok. No more errors just using this line: .load(innerShiv(newHash + " #guts") But now nothing works any more. So strange.

Comment: Yeah you have still got more syntax issues. Try my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! But there is still a problem with innerShiv. So for now I moved back to non HTML5 semantics to solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe hit the little tickbox next to my answer because the problem with your code above was syntax errors which we fixed. The problem with innershiv is probably something to be solved from a different angle.